# How is 妻 written according to PRC and Taiwanese standard?

Tags: characters

Different fonts I see disagree in whether the fifth stroke should pass through the fourth or not.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're halfway to answering your own question. On the zdic page theres a tab called **字源字形**: [妻 字源字形](http://www.zdic.net/z/17/zy/59BB.htm).

Here's the part you're interested in:

> [image]

The stroke you're talking about doesn't poke through in PRC but in Taiwan and HK it does.

Comment: Never noticed this tab! Extremely useful!

Comment: Yeah you can even compare Japanese and Korean characters as well.